# How to optimize hard?

Tags: php

I must optimize hard script. Current runtime ~5 hours.

Script find duplicates in table files use table folders by md5 hash.

DB: MySQL, server: local.
Computer: AsRock Z77 pro4, intel core i7 3770, 12Gb ram.

Code:

```
// find file-duplicates by md5-hash
$current_folder_id = 1;
$select_ids_files = array();

$folders = $this->db->query("
    SELECT `folder_id`
    FROM `sc_folders`
")->result();

if (!$folders)
    exit('folders not found');

$current_files_data = $this->get_files_by_folder_id($current_folder_id);
if (!$current_files_data) {
    exit('!current_files_data');
}

foreach ($folders as $folder) {
    $files = (object)array();
    $files = $this->get_files_by_folder_id($folder->folder_id);

    if (!$files)
        continue;

    if (count($files) > count($current_files_data)) {
        $gl_arr = &$files;
        $nogl_arr = &$current_files_data;
    } else {
        $gl_arr = &$current_files_data;
        $nogl_arr = &$files;
    }

    foreach ($gl_arr as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($nogl_arr as $k => &$v) {
            if ($value->file_hash == $v->file_hash && $value->file_id != $v->file_id) { // an important place for optimize
                $select_ids_files[] = $v->file_id;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($select_ids_files);exit; // id duplicates records
```

Table folders: folder_id, folder_name. (~45 records)
Table files: file_id, file_hash, file_folder_id, file_name. (~1,400,000 records)

Comment: Which part takes all the time? Try profiling it or at least echoing out the time at various points to see which part you need to optimise

Comment: @Anigel `if ($value->file_hash == $v->file_hash && $value->file_id != $v->file_id)` = 99% time.

Comment: It looks like all the file hashes are stored in a database Why not just select the duplicate hashes directly in an sql query something like `select * from files group by hash having count(hash) > 1` instead of 1.4 million loops each of which loops 1.4 million things

Comment: @Anigel I can not be sure that there will be all the replays with your request.

Especially since I can not set duplicate file specify a file folder <20 (because the files are already in use).

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say sorry. If the hashes are in the db then you can simply select duplicate files directly from the db if not then you need to explain more in your question as no where shows anything creating hashes

Comment: Strange I would have expected accessing the disk for the hashes to eat up the time and by your numbers given the file is in both you are doing 1400 a sceond ish. You could swap the if statment so file id is checked first, don't know how much of a difference it will make though.

Comment: Agree with @Anigel if hash was in the db mysql would do the comparison way faster, and you wouldn't be generating 2.8 million hashes in one go...

Comment: @Anigel I'll explain briefly: if run sql-query (your) i get some records. This records belong folders (for example, folders id: 2,4,40). I must set param `is_duplicate`=true for records (from you sql-response). But files (not records in db) where folder_id < 20 used => i can not conduct operations with them.

Comment: @iproger. There is nothing in my query that would have anything to do with folders. If you want to ask a question that shows your table structures and some sample data, preferably with an sqlfiddle then we can show you how to select everything you need.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Why requests for files in a loop? Because "foreach+if hash == hash2" of 10,000 elements * 20 sql-query faster 1sql-query*1,000,000

Comment: @Anigel Look on tables: [link](http://s020.radikal.ru/i717/1308/ec/795e254eee7b.png) and [link](http://s019.radikal.ru/i618/1308/76/06f0b306f654.png)

Comment: We are at cross purposes here. How does a duplicate happen in the first place?

Comment: Try grouping by `file_hash` and adding a where clause to specify which folder: `select * from sc_files where file_folder_id = 1 group by file_hash having count(*) > 1`

Comment: why you don't `compare first by size`?.  File size is an attribute at folder level if you are reading folders, surely no extra IO is needed to do this. On the other hand, IO for md5(FileContent) is dependant on the size of the file, and not a definitive test (for colisions matter). In equality case, you shoud anyway compare byte by byte.

Comment: Not a bad idea. However, the file size may be the same for many files, so I'm not sure that it should be used.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson An example of duplication: different locations and names, but the same content.

Comment: Plan A:  Use SQL to find duplicate md5 values.

Comment: Plan B:  Sort $files; make a single pass through it to find dups.

Comment: Plan C:  Use array_unique, array_diff and maybe some other things to find the dups.

Comment: Plans A, B, C are O(N); your pair of foreachs is O(N*N).  A huge difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not use foreach {foreach {} }. use foreach { in_array() }.

-50% time.

Answer (score 1):

First, it might be *very helpful* to state, what you are actually try to achieve.

From what I can read from the sourcecode:

- You have a datatable, containing links to the files and their hash.
- You want to (periodically) check, if a file has been insterted, changed or removed?

First Question that raises: *HOW* are files inserted, removed or edited? Are Users simple accessing the folder directly, or does it happen through any kind of application?

IF it happens through an application, you should update THAT point, and flag any outdated Entry in the Database. Something like `UPDATE files SET 'requires_approval'=1 WHERE filename LIKE '{$current_changed_file}'`

If that is NOT the case (Users are editing, deleting, inserting files on the File-System Level) You could optimize your check by doing the following:

- Save the timestamp (i.E. the newest modification date of ANY file) inside your database.
- When checking for changes, ONLY take files with a later modification date into account.

Something like

```
foreach ($files as $file){
   if (filemtime($file) > $my_stored_modification_time){
      //refresh the data-row
   }
}
```

(to recognize a deletion, you could iterate over all file-entrys (database) and use `is_file` - for deletions you don't need to care about file-hashes, because you cant even generate them)

Comment: Thanks for the answers (Who set me -1?).

My folders with files.
http://s018.radikal.ru/i504/1308/09/d1a90da9da88.png

Comment: Algorithm:
1. I get a files (~30,000 in week).
2. Every week i created a folder (2013-..-..)
3. Scan files by my program (created xml-list and insert in mysql using php).
3.5. Compare files for delete duplicates.
4. I can give files for other people from old folder (2012-..-..).

Comment 3.5:
I can`t delete foles in old folders (i hope you understand why).

Comment: Still not getting it. As @dognose says the time to check for a duplicate is when the new and possibly duplicate file is added. That would be expensive at the point of adding, but you could also add it to a CheckForDuplicates table and process that in a scheduled background task.